# Can't delete back button in navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have this implementation in my app:

[image]

When I click on "Vendi libro" button, it performs "show segue" and goes to Sell Book View Controller; in this View Controller there is a Navigation Bar with the "Menù" button inherited, so I can return to the Menù View Controller.
Then, if I click on "scan" button it goes to Scanner Controller and also here there is the "back" button to return to Sell Book View Controller.
With ScannerController I scan a QR Code and than return to Sell Book View Controller and here there is the error: in the navigation Bar there is the "back" button to return to Scanner Controller but I want the old "menu" button. How can I have it? Hope to be clear with my explanation

Comment: It sounds as if you're going from your scanner controller to a **different / new** sell book controller instead of returning to the original one.  Use the debugger (or print) to take a look at the value of `self` inside the sell book VC before and after the scan.  If the addresses are different, the objects are different.

Comment: I have printed self and the result is this: <EToSchool.SellBookViewController: 0x101e58d30>

<EToSchool.SellBookViewController: 0x101e31cd0>

Comment: OK, so they're different instances of the controller, which probably means that whatever you're doing to "return to Sell Book View Controller" is not returning but showing a new controller.

Comment: So in the Sell Book View Controller how Can I maintain the back button with "Menù" label and not with other labels? Do I have to delete something in the Navigation Stack or do I have to do something different?

Comment: You need to dismiss your scanner controller so that it truly goes back to the existing SBVC.  Once you have a second one, things have already gone wrong.  To help, I'd need to know all the details of what happens in the app after scanning completes.

Comment: So I have the Sell Book View Controller where I take information of a book. When I click on scan button, it goes to Scanner Controller (with performSegue). With Scanner Controller I scan an ISBN code with the camera and when the camera detects the code, it returns to Sell Book View Controller (also with performSegue) and shows the code in a textField.

Comment: When you want to return from scanning, dismiss the scanner controller instead of executing another segue.  You can use a delegate protocol, or a notification, or a data model object to make the code available on return.

Comment: If I dismiss the Scanner Controller It goes ti the page before the Menu

Comment: That's a different problem.  From what you've posted, I can't say why that's happening, but getting rid of the duplicate is progress.